# GUI web browser to run in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, web-browser, gui, ubuntu

I want to run a GUI web browser on Xubuntu 14.04 but it seems that [neither am I able to nor is it safe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/989044/multiple-web-browsers-crashing-almost-immediately).

So my question is, is there any GUI web browser that I can try?

## Specs:

1. Must run without [SSE2](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005779/processors.html)
2. Must be free
3. Must be as secure as possible
4. Ideally lightweight

## Hardware information:

`~$sudo lshw -short`

```
H/W path        Device      Class       Description
===================================================
                            system      System Name
/0                          bus         A7V8X-X
/0/0                        memory      64KiB BIOS
/0/4                        processor   AMD Athlon(TM) XP 2500+
/0/4/9                      memory      128KiB L1 cache
/0/4/a                      memory      512KiB L2 cache
/0/28                       memory      1GiB System Memory
/0/28/0                     memory      DIMM DRAM Synchronous [empty]
/0/28/1                     memory      DIMM DRAM Synchronous [empty]
/0/28/2                     memory      1GiB DIMM DRAM Synchronous
/0/100                      bridge      VT8377 [KT400/KT600 AGP] Host Bridge
/0/100/1                    bridge      VT8237/VX700 PCI Bridge
/0/100/1/0                  display     NV34 [GeForce FX 5500]
/0/100/10                   bus         VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller
/0/100/10.1                 bus         VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller
/0/100/10.2                 bus         VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller
/0/100/10.3                 bus         USB 2.0
/0/100/11                   bridge      VT8235 ISA Bridge
/0/100/11.1                 storage     VT82C586A/B/VT82C686/A/B/VT823x/A/C PIPC Bus Master IDE
/0/100/11.5                 multimedia  VT8233/A/8235/8237 AC97 Audio Controller
/0/100/12       eth0        network     VT6102/VT6103 [Rhine-II]
/0/100/13                   multimedia  Bt878 Video Capture
/0/100/13.1                 multimedia  Bt878 Audio Capture
/0/1            scsi0       storage     
/0/1/0.0.0      /dev/sda    disk        81GB Maxtor 6Y080L0
/0/1/0.0.0/1    /dev/sda1   volume      8197MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2    /dev/sda2   volume      42GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/3    /dev/sda3   volume      26GiB Extended partition
/0/1/0.0.0/3/5  /dev/sda5   volume      1954MiB Linux swap / Solaris partition
/0/1/0.0.0/3/6  /dev/sda6   volume      24GiB Linux filesystem partition
/0/2            scsi1       storage     
/0/2/0.0.0      /dev/cdrom  disk        SCSI CD-ROM
/0/2/0.1.0      /dev/sr1    disk        DVDRAM GSA-4167B
```

---

`~$ sudo lscpu`

```
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            6
Model:                 10
Stepping:              0
CPU MHz:               1833.287
BogoMIPS:              3666.57
L1d cache:             64K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              512K
```

**Note:** [The related question & answers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/39893/34948) here have no consideration for last two specs given.

Comment: The posted question you link to is about the limitations of the processor and the instruction set. What is your hardware you are running on? Please update your post with a description of your hardware including the type of processor with model number so that people can determine the instruction set supported.

Comment: [10 Useful Commands to Collect System and Hardware Information in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/commands-to-collect-system-and-hardware-information-in-linux/) may help.  See `sudo lshw` in item #2.

Comment: Thanks for the info. You seem to have an Athlon without the SSE2 instruction set which seems to be a baseline for some browsers.  However see  [Best Windows Linux Web Browser Programs for Very Old Computers](http://johnsonyip.com/wordpress/2012/03/19/best-windows-and-linux-web-browsers-for-very-old-computers/) as well as [What browser can I install that will work without SSE2.](http://www.euask.com/topic/8322-What-browser-can-I-install-that-will-work-without-SSE2) and https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39893/what-browser-can-i-use-for-amd-athlon-without-sse2-instruction-set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What browser can I use for AMD Athlon without SSE2 instruction set?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39893/what-browser-can-i-use-for-amd-athlon-without-sse2-instruction-set)